# angularjs $interval function trigger before time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have implemented $interval function inside of angularjs application. When i test this i have noticed that function trigger before a time what i have configured it. Here is a code:

```
var timeInSec=90;
  var promise = $interval(function() {
       $log.info("trigger");
        }, timeInSec*1000);
```

First this trigger after 60 second and then each time after 90 second. Can someone tell me a reason OR is there any other parameter which i need to set that after every 90 second this should need to trigger.

Comment: The code above will trigger every 90 seconds, as expected. If this isn't so in your case, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem.

Comment: thats an unusual behavior because it should work [$interval](http://plnkr.co/edit/7NnMRpg1VBjE6Q9C42dK?p=preview) It works perfectly in my example

Comment: It does work like expected: http://jsfiddle.net/wrh2b2ya/ what is your problem so?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct and works totally fine in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/varunsukheja/5y2ojymt/)

but it does not work here in StackOverflow, I have modified a little bit to make it work here in StackOverflow
Check the running code below.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$interval', function($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.title = 'Hello world';

  var timeInSec = 2;
  $scope.promise = function() {
    $interval(function() {
      console.log("trigger");
    }, timeInSec * 1000);
  };

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
  <div>{{title}}</div>
  <button ng-click=promise()>
    Click Me
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: How does this solve the users question? In other words, how does this solve an unknown problem?

Comment: instead of directly assigning $interval function to promise variable, I have created a promise function and used $interval function inside that

Comment: We see this. But how does this solve the users question? Wrapping an `$interval` into a function has no effect. It just wraps it into a function thats all.Your fiddle is also showing an error `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null`.

Comment: I agree, might be some issue with compiler used here

Comment: It's nice that you try to help this user but this answer is useless without knowing the problem.